# Need to create a plot with panda series and numpy array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a panda time series (x) with time index t and numpy array (y) of same length. i need to create a plot of x,y on y axis and time (t) on x axis.

```
x.shape (320,)    
y.shape (320,1)
```

i tried converting numpy array but it gives me an error(Data must be 1-dimensional).

```
pd.Series(y,index=x.index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `x` is a panda series and `y` is a numpy array

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x.index.values, y, label="y")
plt.plot(x.index.values, x.value, label="x")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: you want to keep it for the plot or in general? because this is not a mutation operation, the original series still exists. if you want to convince yourself `print(x)` after the `plt.plot`

Comment: ahh ok, i'll fix the answer, it wasn't clear from your question. Also if it is a series, it is a one dimensional datframe so I assume the 'time' you are referring to is the index?

Comment: hey my x.index.value is null but this works fine plt.figure()
plt.plot(x.index, y, label="y")
plt.plot(x.index, x, label="x")
plt.legend()
plt.show()